# Dynamic database creation on button click

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am facing a problem that when i make the setup file of my application developed in vb.net the database file will not be attached to it, as a solution i wish to create the database @ first run of the application through the following code

```
Dim myCommand As String
Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=soft_billing;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
        myCommand = "CREATE database soft_billing"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
        Try
           cmd.Connection.Open()
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
           cmd.Connection.Close()
        Catch
            MsgBox(" Already installed database", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " MaS InfoTech- Warning")

        End Try
```

it will not generated the required data base,
help me please, thanks in advane

Comment: How can the Initial Catalog be "soft_billing" if that's the very database that you're trying to create?

Comment: thanks jmcilhinney.. i got the mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myCommand As String
Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
        myCommand = "CREATE database soft_billing"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
        Try
           cmd.Connection.Open()
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
           cmd.Connection.Close()
        Catch
            MsgBox(" Already installed database", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, " MaS InfoTech- Warning")

        End Try
```